# How to remove the 'Reload trusted' button when opening blend file

Tags: python, blend-files

I would like to try out the new SheepIt renderfarm service with a short film I'm making. The problem is, my short film makes use of the Cookie Flex Rig (http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/61707). Everytime I open the file on my machine, I have to set 'Reload trusted' to see the characters as the rig uses a lot of python code. However, it appears the renderfarm doesn't ignores this and renders without 'Reload trusted' which resulted in weird artifacts.

How would I go about making my blend file open without the 'Reload trusted' popping up? I've tried the f-curve version fix, removing rigify ui python code, and still get the 'Reload trusted'.

Comment: It seems sheepit disables python auto execution (The seem to be running blender with the `--disable-autoexec` flag), so no matter what you do it will be disabled when rendered by sheepit.

Comment: Sheepit is a distributed render farm that shares users computers to do the work. If the users allowing the use of their computer have an exclude path that includes the location of sheepit files then that might override the -y cli option. Sounds like it could be a situation of mixed results as far as auto-scripts go. It could be useful to clarify what takes precedence, prefs or cli so I am [asking that question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/auto-run-scripts-security-options)

Comment: @sambler The CLI takes precedence (just tested it). Sheepit downloads it's own portable version of blender and puts it in `/tmp`, so local user prefs don't apply. I imagine they are disabling auto exec for security reasons (so users aren't vulnerable to jobs containing malicious python)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried activating "Auto Run Python Scripts" in the user prefs?
[image: Auto Run Python Scripts Setting]

Setting this option, removed the "Reload Trusted" button whilst using add ons for me.

Comment: AFAIK this only affects the way your local version of blender handles scripted drivers, I don't think it will help with a render farm.

Comment: Thanks Phip, it still doesn't allow SheepIt to render the rig, but I found this useful on my own machine (no more having to press 'Reload trusted' everytime!)