# Auto-run scripts security options

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

We have a preferences option to enable auto-run of python scripts when opening blend files. We can also add paths that are excluded from auto-running scripts. Then we have a cli options to enable or disable auto-running scripts and to bypass the startup.blend with `--factory-startup`.

In regard to auto-running scripts which of these options overrides all others?

If my startup.blend disables auto-run, can a python script be run from the cli to enable auto-run for the blend being opened?

Does `--factory-startup` bypass my auto-run settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the order is as follows (in order from weakest to strongest):

1. Startup .blend settings (does not override anything)
2. `--factory-startup` will override all startup .blend preferences (including auto exec), but the default setting for auto exec is disabled (disallowing auto execution globally).
3. `-y` (`--enable-autoexec`) *enables* 
   `-Y` (`--disable-autoexec`) *disables*
   Both these options override the startup `.blend` auto exec preferences (including when used with `--factory-startup`) allowing auto execution. Note that it does not edit the preferences (even temporarily), it just allows execution.
4. Running a script with `-P` (`--python`, `--python-text`, `--python-expr`) will execute the script immediately ignoring auto-execution settings. It is possible to enable auto-execution from such a script.

Comment: 4. But it only allows to run the script given to -P, or does it also allow other scripts? I guess only that script is executed, but can probably import and execute others. Text datablocks registered as module shouldn't be allowed, only because a certain script was passed for execution.

Comment: @CoDEmanX - clarified the `-P` behavior.