# What does 'Autorun disabled' statement mean?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, drivers

Could someone explain me what does this statement mean and what option should I click when it pops up?

[image]

[image]

Comment: When did it pop up? What failed to execute when it did?

Comment: read also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/auto-run-scripts-security-options/7674#7674 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/auto-run-scripts-security-options/7674#7674

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Blender comes bundled with python. Malicious scripts written in python could potentially damage your computer. As a security measure the automatic running of python scripts has been disabled since version 2.6.

What this most likely means is that there is a piece of python code that is controlling the driver.

You can allow blender to auto run scripts by changing your user preferences. To do this press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, then head over to *File* and enable *Auto Run Python Scripts*. Although it is unlikely that someone will distribute a malicious blend file you should still make sure where you download .blend file from

[image]

More information on [Scripting & Security](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/security.html#scripting-security) at the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

By default Auto Run is disabled. It's a safety feature to prevent untrusted code to be executed. To enable it go to User Preferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> and in the File tab check the **Auto Run Python Scripts** box.

[image]