# Animation on blender 2.72 does not work on blender 2.71

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have done some animations on my Mac pro using blender 2.72. However, my laptop has not GPU. So, I am using an other linux pc to do the rendering using blender 2.71. Unfortunately, the animation does not work as expected on linux machine.
I remark that the armature animation is the same and work as on my Laptop, but the clothes and body does not follow the animation. What is the problem and How can I fix it ?

Comment: It's always risky mixing version numbers for the same project, in my experience. Is it not possible to install a newer version of Blender on the Linux machine?

Comment: Blender is quite compatible between versions.. I suspect you have [drivers disabled](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21312/599) and/or missing physics caches.

Comment: @gandalf3 I have resolved this poblem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by checking this option

[image]

[image]