# Primitive Z Function- Changing Equation in Realtime

Tags: mesh

I am using the following function:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_z_function_surface(equation = "(x*y)/10", div_x = 16, div_y = 16, size_x = 15, size_y = 15)
```

to plot a 3D graph as a mesh. Is it possible for me to change the equation passed in with a python script, without deleting and re-instantiating a new mesh object?

Apologies if this question is dumb, just not super familiar with Blender.

Comment: Does this help?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/animating-z-surface-math-functions

Comment: I saw that earlier, but I couldn't seem to get it to work- I'll take a look again though. Thanks!

Comment: @RobotKarel314 If it is my answer you are having issues with, don't hesitate to ask via comment on A.