# rotation copied every second circle

Tags: constraints

My question is pretty simple.

How to make an object copy rotation of another object with same speed but only every second circle. I know I can animate that using keyframes, but I need to have in constraint.

Comment: Do you mean rotate half as fast, or stop completely every other rotation?

Comment: Stop completely every other rotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a scripted [driver](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-expression) to the desired rotation axis of the object with the intermittent rotation, using the following expresion:

```
var*(int((var/(2.0*pi))%2))
```

where the variable `var`, (or whatever you want to call it) refers to the relevant rotation (X,Y,or Z) of the driving object.

[image]

Here, the Z rotation of the triangle is  being driven by the expression, in which `var` refers to the the Z rotation of the square.

EDIT in response to your comment:

We can make the expression a little more general by implicitly casting True and False to 1 and 0:

```
var*(int((var/(2.0*pi))%3)==1)
```

In this version, the number where the `3` is determines the number of turns in the cycle, and the number where the `1` is says which of the turns to follow, with 0 as the last, counting back. So this example would make the driven object follow the driver on the second of every three turns.

So, in order to have alternating rotations, in the example below, the green triangle uses:

```
var*(int((var/(2.0*pi))%2)==1)
```

..and the yellow triangle uses:

```
var*(int((var/(2.0*pi))%2)==0)
```

[image]

Any more than this - say, "the second and fifth out of every seven".. and it would probably be tidier to write a little function, and add it to the `driver_namespace`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I also tried making third object that rotates when the second object doesn't I tried this
var*(int((var/(4.0*pi))%2))
Bu it hasn't worked out.

Comment: @Michal.. I've made an edit to cover this..

Comment: Consider div instead of mod in this case. ` `var * (var // twopi)` Mod is handy for mapping  [eg  mapping  on 0, 1 for offset on an orbit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118300/15543)   div `//` wil give you the whole number that you are calculating with int-divide-modulus combo

Comment: Thanks, @batFINGER, I'm stumped. I can see how to get rid of the `int`, (e.g. `var* (((var//(2.0*pi)%5))in[1,2])`) but  I can't figure out how to have an infinite cyclic function without a `%` _somewhere_. Please go ahead and fix the answer, if you like.

Comment: Sorry re confusion, was pointing out that revs or laps can be calculated using div not that mod and int were always avoidable.   The ternary operator is another (_often more_) readable way eg `var if 1.0 <= (var // twopi) % 5 <= 2.0 else 0` Ternary op can be nested.

Comment: As  pointed out often its easier to make a method in the driver namespace to avoid the single line madness. Akin to print pages '[1, 3, 4-6]` Would like to see a subexpression in drivers akin to math surface to cut down long expressions.. . Mapping equation to 0 or 1 and driving a copy rotation constraint influence is another way that can be less complex equation wise.     Is the square above slightly leading the triangle? 8UV's too man.. envious lol.

Comment: @batFINGER I agree. The little expression window has the effect of turning everything into code golf.  I was once a bit of a Perl camel, but I'm way off even apprentice Pythonista, so your crit is always more than welcome. I don't _think_ the square is leading.. the skew dotted line is to the manual rotation cursor, out of shot. I seem to have kicked off at about -93. Envious? I don't get the impression your rep. needs a voting system.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you very much! I tried it and both objects skip every third circle, so object A rotates all the time then object B does 360 and stops then object C stops and does 360. After this I want the B to come again, but they both stop for one circle.

Comment: @Michal.. see extension to edit.. hope I've got what you mean, this time :)

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! Thank you! But, could you also add offset to this?

Comment: @Michal    Just bracket the whole expression up and add the offset at the end.. (or the beginning)... e.g. (expression)+(pi/2) would shift the rotation of the driven object by 90 degrees anticlockwise..(all angles are expressed in radians to _try_ and keep everything short) :D..