# How to change direction of the camera along a path?

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

i am making a turn round animation but i want the camera to go the right right direction instead of left, but i cant find any option do it,

[image]

Comment: @Chris https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#generator

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118300/15543 (negate the expression to go the other way)  `-(frame / 40) % 1.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you want in 2.79.

As you've already done:

- Create your camera and leave it at the origin
- Create your path, in your case, a Bezier Circle, centered on the tracked object
- Create your tracked object, in your case an empty at the origin.
- Set a constraint on your camera to track to the tracked object.

Finally, add a *Follow Path* constraint to the camera.

To get tracking to work the way you want, you can either reverse the animation or rotate the curve 180 degrees on the Y axis in edit mode.

Rotating the curve works because the camera follows the direction of the curve.  If you enable the overlay to show the curve's normals while you have the curve in edit mode, you'll see something like this:

[image: curve showing clockwise facing normals]

In my example, the curve's normals appear to face clockwise when viewed from the top, and my camera will rotate clockwise.

Now I rotate the curve *in edit mode* 180 degrees.  The normals point counterclockwise as seen from the top and my camera will rotate clockwise.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! i rotate in edit mode and worked :) i was looking forever for an option in the properties could never have thought about rotating the circle in edit mode :D saved me a lot of time