# Linear Extrapolation of a Particle Emission Trail

Tags: animation, particles

### My Goal

...is to have a particle-trail-tail continue infinitely, despite having a "Frame Start / Frame End" property in the Particle System tab, rather than using keyframe animation.

My animation is a model of the solar system, where the planets are constrained to curves, and emit a particle trail which conforms to the same curve.

[image: animation of the trails ending]

### My Setup So Far

- The orbital paths are curves.
- The planets are empties, using Object Constraint, targeted to the orbit-curves.

  - A UV sphere is parented to each empty as the planet object.
  - A plane is parented to the empty as the (trail) emitter object.
- The orbit animations are keyframed on 1 and 360 as the curve offset percentage, and then set to **linear extrapolation** in the graph editor.
- The particle trails have "Frame Start / End" properties, which are not animatable properties, rather than something that I know how to keyframe.

### The Problem

The animation above is frames 264 - 456. The extrapolated curve motion continues past frame 360, but the frame-coded particle emitter does not.

I thought I would use linear extrapolation like I did for the orbits themselves, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

### The Request

I'm looking for a way to make the trails continue indefinitely, regardless of how many frames the ending animation turns out to be.

### Additional Potentially Useful Screenshots

My object organization and hierarchy:

[image: My object organization and hierarchy]

My particle emission settings:

[image: My particle emission settings]

My trail shrink is a texture blend, using a ColorRamp from white to black. The Influence is set to Size. The Mapping is set to Strand/Particle:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Array and Curve Modifier.**

*Going to offer up an alternative approach to using a particle system*

[image]

Can make a similar set up using an array and curve modifier.

Slap together a Very quick example

- Icosphere as planet
- Add and empty, make the icosphere its parent. It will be used as an array offset object, *ie* its distance from ico will separate, its scale will cause each to be smaller.
- Add an orbit.
- Add an array modifier to the icosphere, with object offset targeting the empty
- Add a curve modifier, targeting the orbit circle.
- Have arbitrarily chosen the X axis to follow the curve
- Ico Can be set to orbit infinitely by setting a driver on its X location based on the frame [Continuous Looping animation - Differing rotational speeds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118290/continuous-looping-animation-differing-rotational-speeds)

Comment: Hi @batFINGER, thanks for the reply. I find your method to be simple, elegant, and more clever than I was being with the particle system. -- I'd had my planet anchored to an empty, with the thought that later on I'll make the planet itself rotate around the empty. Do you know a way to use both rotation and trails with your method? Thanks again!

Comment: If just the planet is to rotate, not all the "followers" One quick method that comes to mind is a slightly larger planet with copy loc constraint to ico.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with animation nodes, but...the first sphere is not the biggest one, i don't know if you can live with that...

here is the nodes setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

you can change the trail length by changing the fade length value

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chris, this is neat. I don't think it will work for my planet trails, but I'll definitely be studying this because I can see many future uses for it!