# Rigify's "Generate Rig" button just copies the rig

Tags: rigging, bones, scale, rigify

I use Blender for a few months and till now everything went fine. The last time I open Blender I got this message:
[image: security warning]

Ever since that every time I try to do generate rig, the bones just duplicate themselves and that is what I see in the layers

[image: screenshot 2]

I didn't add any addons that are not built in Blender, and I tried to open the file from blender_factory_startup and it didn't work, I also tried to press "scale" to make sure this is not the problem. (btw, why do we need to do "scale" for?)

If anyone knows something about it I will appreciate any help. And for anyone understanding python and can get something out of this

[image: log window]

Comment: Does this help? If so, then this question should be considered for closing.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21312/what-does-autorun-disabled-statement-mean

Comment: The security warning is because Rigify runs some script to initialize the custom buttons in the N-panel. That's normal.
When you have already a generated rig and you want to update it from the metarig make sure the rig object is not hidden in the viewport or else the *Generate Rig* button will duplicate the metarig for some reason.