# How to launch render from command line with load trusted option?

Tags: command-line

How to launch render from command line with load trusted option? I haven't found any keys for allowing launching of scripts in a file:

```
   $ /opt/blender-2.73-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender  -b ./v/Scenes/10/sc10.blend -o //out/ -s 064 -e 126 -a
   ......
   skipping driver 'frame', automatic scripts are disabled
   ......
```

Is there any way to launch scripts, if I don't have an active GUI and can't set the "autorun scripts" parameter?

Comment: Ups, I find it here http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Security (key: -y)

Comment: Good to know. You should definitly post it as an answer as soon as you have the required reputation (I think 15 rep is what you need).

Comment: @maddin45 There are no reputation restrictions on asking or answering basic questions.

Comment: @iKlsR you are right. You only need the 15 rep for the checkbox [to answer your own question while asking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7674/935) explains which options override others.