# Check polygon count without opening file?

Tags: polycount

Is there a way to run blender without opening it and return the polygon count of different obj files?

Comment: Do you want polycounts of objects inside .blend, or do you want to use blender to examine multiple .obj files on disk?

Comment: could you perhaps use a blender file with an auto-executing script that imports .obj files & dumps details to log file?

Comment: see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/auto-run-scripts-security-options

Comment: @Jerryno I'd like to have blender check multiple .obj files

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks that sounds like it would work well. I'm completely new to creating scripts and using blender behind the scenes is there anywhere you could point me to get started learning about how to do something like that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'm confident it could work in that way: try starting here perhaps https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_65_5/info_quickstart.html